# Landscape with Displacement Modifier

Tags: displacement

I've seen several tutorials online where they create a terrain-ish grid mesh by adding a displacement modifier with a cloud texture. The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to get the scale right. Mine just looks like bumpy noise, whereas theirs is nice undulating hills. Is there any way to 'zoom in' on the texture? I feel like I'm doing just what they're doing in the tutorial videos, but not getting the same result at all.

[image: Mine]

[image: Theirs]

Comment: go into the Texture panel and change the Size of the texture. Also right click and Shade Smooth

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! I tried messing with the size attribute, but now I realize I wasn't changing the value enough. I had to go from 0.25 to 9

Comment: also maybe apply the scale of your plane

Comment: Note that some fields ranges are hard-coded for scrubbing but you can manually input higher values if the scale still doesn't match the scale of your scene